# How to efficiently render a dynamic list of subelements in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

Given a Vaadin application where a user can add and remove elements of a list that is also rendered in the browser, I am wondering what the most efficient way of handling such manipulations would be. Currently, I am simply using the `add` and `remove` methods.

I am only experienced with Apache Wicket where one should avoid to manipulate the component tree for performance reasons. In the documentation, I only found a section on how to handle [repeated elements in Polymer](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/polymer-templates/tutorial-template-list-bindings.html) but nothing on how this can be done using the "simple" API.

Am I choosing the right approach?

Answer (score 3):

The Vaadin UI code runs on the server, so the add/remove operations don't affect the DOM directly. When a response is sent back to the browser, Vaadin will look at the difference between the previous UI state and the current and send appropriate instructions to the browser client to update the DOM. In this case, the instruction would be something like "remove the following components:...". The actual DOM manipulation is handled by Vaadin, and is not something you can affect yourself.

If you run into performance issues, help us out by filing an issue ticket on GitHub, so we can take a look at it https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues